# TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined on Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, puppeteer

i would like to iterate the first six "posts" items and if that contains a certain class : `.update-components-text.relative.feed-shared-update-v2__commentary` it warn me with a msg.

Anyone can explain what i'm wrong on my code?

```
await page.goto("https://www.linkedin.com/");
const posts = await page.$$(".relative")

for (let i = 0; i < Math.min(6, posts.length); i++) { 
      if (posts[i].classList.contains(".update-components-text.relative.feed-shared-update-v2__commentary")) {
        console.log("Post! detect");
      }
  }
```

That unfortunately get a TypeError about `contains` :

`(node:19930) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined`

Comment: Log classList it's probably undefined.

Comment: @DreamyPlayer How can do him to recognize ? according to the [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains) i can

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the site, but `classList` probably won't have periods. It's an array. You should try printing it out. Also, it's a property on a native DOM element in the browser, not an element handle in Node. Plop that code into an `evaluate` or use `getAttribute`.

Comment: @ggorlen the site was linkedin, the problem is how i can differentiate a post & repost on this site ? that why i use `classList `

Comment: You can use `classList`, but not like this. Your `.contains()` call is malformed and will basically never be true. It doesn't do what you think it does. You'll need to loop over each class you want to check without the `.`s and call `contains` on each one.